# Ignore SQL Query error in Excel Macro

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a set of queries in a EXCEL macro, that are executed when the macro is started

If, for some queries, the indicated fields don't exist in the database, executing the macro gives the following error:

> Run-time error '3021': Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record
>   has been deleted. requested operation requires a current record.

I want to protect the execution of the queries so that when this situation exists (lack of corresponding column in the database or any other kind of error related to the query), the macro simply continues the execution and don't output any kind of error, leaving the corresponding cell where the result supposedly would be outputted in blank.

Relevant piece of code:

```
Range("G7").Select
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT ....")
strResult = rs.Fields(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that `BOF` and `EOF` arent true in an if statement. Using your code above, you could do this like so:

```
Range("G7").Select
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT ....")

If Not rs.BOF and Not rs.EOF Then

    strResult = rs.Fields(0)

End If
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks. Also, in case of error the cell can be leaved in blank by simply inserting something like: Else Sheets(1).Range("T30").Value = ""

Comment: Yep that's the one. Looking at the code though, looks like you assign the returned value to a string called `strResult` so you'd want that to be empty.